Customize how a class instance is returned in ASP.NET Core responses
Given this class
public class ModelErrors
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; set; } = [];

    public void Add(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        // Check if this property already has an error

        if (Errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out List<string>? propErrors))
        {
            propErrors.Add(value);
        }
    }
}

How do I make it so that when this code is executed...
ModelErrors errs = new();
errs.Add("hello", "world");

return BadRequest(errs);

... I can customize how the Errors property is returned to the client? For example to turn it from Dictionary<string, List<string>> to Dictionary<string, string> where the value is a join of all errors?

You can register a custom JSON converter, but I don't know how you expect to convert a List<string> to string?

If the nature of a dictionary is hidden in ModelErrors why even store it as List?And not just as string and directly concatenating the error in a way you want in Add?

How would I apply the custom JSON converter once I created it? I'd convert List<string> to string by using string.Join(',', Errors)

Use builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions and then option.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add() in the configuration delegate.

You can use JsonConverter to customize serialization. Create a custom JsonConverter and then apply JsonConverter attribute on ModelErrors class. Here is an example for your reference:
My custom Converter:
public class ModelErrorsConverter : JsonConverter<ModelErrors>
{
    public override ModelErrors Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ModelErrors value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var kvp in value.GetErrors())
        {
            writer.WriteString(kvp.Key, string.Join(", ", kvp.Value));
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

ModelErrors:
[JsonConverter(typeof(ModelErrorsConverter))]
public class ModelErrors
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; set; } = [];

    public void Add(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        // Check if this property already has an error

        if (Errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out List<string>? propErrors))
        {
            propErrors.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            propErrors = new List<string> { value };
            Errors[propertyName] = propErrors;
        }
    }

public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetErrors()
{
    return Errors;
}

Controller:
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    ModelErrors errs = new();
    errs.Add("error", "list1");
    errs.Add("error", "list2");
          
    return BadRequest(errs);
}

Result:

